# How to include UIColor to the value of a Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: dictionary, swift

I want to initiate an Array of Dictionary in Swift, where the value of one of keys is of type `UIColor`. So I want to create the following Array:

```
var myArr:[[String: Any]] = [
    ["name": "mark", "age": "30", "color": UIColor.blackColor()]
]
```

However, the code above returns an `AssertString is not convertible to UIColor` error. But the `Any` should be used in `UIColor`, I don't know why it returns such errors nor what it means.

So how can I resolve the issue and use `UIColor` instance properly?

### UPDATE

Sorry but I found that the actual error was not on the snippet above - it is on the following part, which is from my own `UIColor` extension:

```
["name": "pete", "age" "25", "color": UIColor(R:245.0, G:168.0, B:13.0, A:1.0)]
```

And I created a separate file named `UIColor+ColorWithInt.swift` (not sure about the proper name convention, but I've been just porting my old Objective-C app to Swift, which is the reason I used `Dictionary` to represent the data above).

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    func colorWithR(R: CGFloat, G: CGFloat, B: CGFloat, A: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: (R/255), green: (G/255), blue: (B/255), alpha: A)
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using `AnyObject` instead of `Any`? In any case this looks like a good use-case for a `struct` rather than using a `Dictionary`

Comment: It returns an error: `Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'`.

Comment: Strange, what beta are you using? A Beta 7 playground works fine for both `Any` and `AnyObject` for me

Comment: I use Beta 7. I don't use playground though.

Comment: It could be the scope that you're defining this in. Are you trying to define this globally or within a class?

Comment: Works for me in playground and an iOS app.

Comment: @Gardecolo responded to your update in my answer

Comment: Chris, Thanks. As to the naming convention of the extension file, what do you suggest?

Comment: I like the + convention from ObjC, I would personally stick with that until I see what the industry shifts to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I'd suggest using a struct or some other concrete data structure for this scenario.

```
import UIKit

struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var color: UIColor
}

var myArr:[Person] = [
    Person(name: "mark", age: 30, color: UIColor.blackColor())
]
```

Or as a class...

```
class Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var color: UIColor

    init(name: String, age: Int, color: UIColor) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.color = color
    }
}

var myArr:[Person] = [
    Person(name: "mark", age: 30, color: UIColor.blackColor())
]
```

**RE: UPDATE**

I think you want something like this...

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(R: CGFloat, G: CGFloat, B: CGFloat, A:CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: (R/255.0), green: (G/255.0), blue: (B/255.0), alpha: A)
    }
}

var red = UIColor(R: 255, G: 0, B: 0, A: 1)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a struct over a class? But I agree, a Dictionary is not a good choice.

Comment: That I am still trying to figure out as far as best practices go. I figure start with the lowest denominator and move up as you need things that the other types provide. Normally I would have picked a class, but after some reading last week I would start with a struct and see if I need the capabilities of a class. Again, I am still (like all of us I am sure) trying to figure out best practices in Swift.

Comment: Here is the article I read @Zaph, what do you think? http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/tuples-structs-enums.html

Comment: I agree but would take a class over a struct, at least at this time since a struct is not an object and creates issues with AnyObject. Another reason is copyingon struct as opposed to reference on class. struct has advantages in some thread situations. I also read that blog.

Comment: Note that Chris does not even discuss classes so there is no argument for a struct over a class.

Comment: Yeah, I just got done looking over it again and noticed it doesn't talk about classes. I definitely don't disagree with using a class here.

Comment: Chris, I mistook what was causing the error. I updated the post. So it might not be related to how `UIColor` should be represented and instead to how to properly incorporate `UIColor's extension`. Sorry...

Comment: @Zaph I found the other thing I read this weekend from GitHub, https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide?utm_content=buffer92806&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer#prefer-structs-over-classes

Comment: OK but the example is a toy. There are no methods `Vehicle` and its rational is that polymorphic subclasses are needed, that is usually notthe case in code developers write,that is we rarly subclass our own classes. There is really no reasons given to prefer struct over class. I woul dreally like to hear one other than immutability.

Comment: @ChrisWagner Apple supplied guidelines: •The structure’s primary purpose is to encapsulate a few relatively simple data values.
•It is reasonable to expect that the encapsulated values will be copied rather than referenced when you assign or pass around an instance of that structure.
•Any properties stored by the structure are themselves value types, which would also be expected to be copied rather than referenced.
•The structure does not need to inherit properties or behavior from another existing type.

Comment: Yeah, I think a Person makes more sense as a class.

Comment: Note that using a dictionary has the advantage that you can save it as part of a property list, e.g. when using `NSCoding`.